# How to reload tableViewCell only in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is there any way that I could reload only tableViewCell only but don't make it reload tableView section title View ? when I switched UITableViewCell I want to update data reload change

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch self[selectedIndex] {

        case .tracks:

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! TracksCell
         return cell

        case .playlists:

          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellPlayListId, for: indexPath) as! PlaylistCell

        return cell

        }
```

What I want to do is just reload UITableViewCell only I don't want to reload this code below

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {}
```

if I use tableView.reload() it will effected my style in viewForHeaderInSection Because I have added UIViewScroll

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 11):

If you want to reload only particular  tableView cell then use this:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: rowNumber, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

It reload only cell not the section.

Comment: what is rowNumber ?

Comment: @Kristoff declaration is func reloadRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], with animation: UITableViewRowAnimation), where indexPath is an array of NSIndexPath objects identifying the rows to reload.

Comment: @Kristof rowNumber means which number of cell you to want to reload. If you want to reload cell number 2 then you write like.               
                                                                                                                              tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)], with: .automatic)

Comment: rowNumber is essentially `foo_rowNumber`

Answer (score 2):

Reload the Particular `UITableViewCell`

```
tableviewCart.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .none)
```

Comment: If you want reload tableview cell

Answer (score 1):

Look for the table view delegate methods for reloading views. These are:

```
open func reloadSections(_ sections: IndexSet, with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation)

open func reloadRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation)

open func reloadData()
```

Here in your case, `reloadRows` will be the best suitable option, as:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: <[IndexPath]>, with: .automatic)
```

Where, `<[IndexPath]>` is the array of index path of the cells. For example:

```
let cell0FromSection0 = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
let cell2FromSection0 = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
let cell1FromSection1 = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 1)

tableView.reloadRows(at: [cell0FromSection0, cell2FromSection0, cell1FromSection1], with: .automatic)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reload particular cell in `UITableView` with below code.

```
let cellNmber = IndexPath(row: rowNumber, section: sectionNummber)
tableView.reloadRows(at: [cellNmber], with: .automatic)
```

or

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [cellNmber], with: .none)
```

If you want to reload cell with default animation then go with `.automatic`.
If you want to reload cell without animation then go with `.none`.
You can also reload multiple cell in a `tableView` by providing `IndexPath` array.
e.g.

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [cellNmber1,cellNmber3,cellNmber5], with: .automatic)
```