# how to call manually cellforrowat of tableview manually in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to call (**cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath**)
method manually from a button how can i accomplish that for the record i already have tried reload data method on the `UITableView`.
It did not work.

`self.myTableView.reloadData()`

Why i need to do that is because i am trying to implement a solution from stackoverflow the solution looks like this:

```
func configureVisibleCells(for tableView: UITableView?, animated: Bool) {
    self.tableView(tableView, configureRowsAtIndexPaths: tableView?.indexPathsForVisibleRows, animated: animated)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView?, configureRowsAtIndexPaths indexPaths: [Any]?, animated: Bool) {
    for indexPath in indexPaths as? [IndexPath] ?? [] {
        let cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView?.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        if cell != nil {
            self.tableView(tableView, configureCell: cell, forRowAt: indexPath, animated: animated)
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView?, configureCell cell: UITableViewCell?, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?, animated: Bool) {
    // Cell configuration
}
```

"Configure the Cell in the

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView?, configureCell cell: UITableViewCell?, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?, animated: Bool) method and call this method in your tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell .
```

and when you need to reload visible cells call the method

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell"
```

Now i need to call it as the guy who posted the solution said so.

Comment: No use case would need that as it's called with reload , post your code ..

Comment: Can i ask why you need to call cellForRowAt manually? what is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: Don't do that. **Never** call `cellForRowAt` *manually*. To reload single rows call [`reloadRows(at:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows)

Comment: Can you give me a snippet of how to call reloadRows

Comment: @SabaAbbasi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567995/how-to-reload-tableviewcell-only-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` manually. That is to be called only by the system otherwise it will result in undefined behaviour. Instead what you can do is call a function that will in turn will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` internally. This is because before calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, system needs to call other methods to be able to layout the cell properly.

**For example**: number of rows, sections, height, etc.

You can use `reloadRows(at:with:)` function of `UITableView` to reload the rows of visible cells.

Have a look at this: [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows).